# My VM instances on Google Cloud Platform do not work after increasing SSD size

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, ssd

Could you please help fix my emergent `Google Cloud Platform` problem? The configuration information as follow:

- The VM instances name is “cchatty”
- Machine type: n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)
- CPU platform: Intel Broadwell
- Zone: us-west1-c
- Service account: `843833239332-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Today, I increased my SSD size of VM instances, and restarted it, after that I can not open this instances, and my website on this instance has also shut the service, the site is www.cchatty.com. So I want to log in the shell via SSH, but it is also failed and told me the port 22 issues “`Connection Failed. We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.`”

Now our website cannot be open and also we can not log in the Linux shell. That’s very serious for us, our website service is shut down for customers.

By the way, we have another instance group, it works well, we don’t increase the SSD size. We think it must some problem during increase the SSD size.

Comment: I log in with gcloud, I found all working files deleted, it looks reset after increasing SSD size.

Comment: that's fixed, it is the CentOS 6 issue. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/111154121) on  Centos 6 when the kernel is updated to 2.6.32-754.el6 version the VM instance will lose their default gateway. Which is already fixed and CentOS 6 has updated packages available now. However if you are not using the updated package and experiencing the same issue, you can follow the following workaroud:

you can add a simple bash script to the [start-up script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptlocalfile) with the following:

"#!/bin/bash
route add default gw [default_gateway_ip] eth0"

Where "[default_gateway_ip]" is the default gateway IP address of the VM instances region. You can find this IP address by doing the following:

1. In the Console go to VPC Network>VPC Networks
2. Use the Gateway IP address that is used for the Region where your VM instance is being hosted from.

After you add this to the Startup script on the VM instance and start it back up, you should now have network connectivity again.

Also in order to implement a Startup script on a existing VM instance, do the following:

1. Stop the VM instance
2. Follow the steps in the attached [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) starting at Step 3 where it says to expand Management, disk, networking, SSH keys section.
3. Save the changes
4. Start the VM instance